# Postgres - delete record after trigger

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I have a postgres table with some triggers that fire if records are udpated or deleted. They basically archive the records so they are not trully deleted - they just change certain attributes so the records are not displayed in corresponding views.

Sometimes I want to manually delete a record for good, but I can't do it because the trigger fires and does it's thing if I execute DELETE query.

Example:
`DELETE FROM records WHERE operator = 20`

Is there a way to run DELETE query and bypass a trigger that fires on DELETE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a setup like this, I think the typical approach is to avoid granting any direct privileges on the underlying table, and put your `INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `DELETE` triggers on the view (allowing the table owner to change it as needed).

If you are the table owner, you can use [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) to temporarily `DISABLE` and re-`ENABLE` the trigger. As long as you do all of this within a transaction, you'll be safe against concurrent `DELETE`s, though they'll block until your transaction commits.

If you have superuser privileges, you can also prevent triggers from firing by setting [`session_replication_role`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SESSION-REPLICATION-ROLE) to `replica`, provided that the trigger in question hasn't been configured to fire on replicated databases.

Comment: I think the disable/enable trigger way is what you want. Maybe you can use the logical decoding feature in newer PostgreSQL versions to write an audit log (into a separate table) - without firing costly triggers all the time. This way you can delete records from the audit table without hassle.